# The usage of the 2,700-square-foot colonial

Tags: phrase-usage

I have a question on "**the 2,700-square-foot colonial**", which I think it should be "**the 2,700-square-foot colonial house**". Colonial is an adjective word. I know the grammar 'the + adjective', which denotes that kind of persons/things. But in this context, it specifically refers to that single house.

So, is it an idiomatic usage? Or any grammar rule could support the usage?

> Located at 1428 N. Genesee Avenue, in Los Angeles, California, **the
>   2,700-square-foot colonial** was sold in 2013 for $2.1 million.

This is [the source](https://www.yahoo.com/gma/stories-behind-homes-classic-halloween-horror-flicks-112203494--abc-news-Halloween.html).

Comment: It's idiomatic in the real estate trade.  You can't do it with just any adjective.

Comment: I see it's a common usage of 'the + adjective', like the poor, the good, the sick, the accused, the right, the wrong,... But they seem to denote a category, not to be specific.

Comment: I might think *the 2,700-square-foot colonial* refers to any house that is 2,700-square-foot and colonial, not merely referring to this house (Located at 1428 N. Genesee Avenue, in Los Angeles, California).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Colonial*** is both an adjective and a noun. So you can say a ***colonial house*** or simply ***colonial*** and they mean the same thing.

Same with all popular styles of real estate in the U.S.:

> The 2700+ square-foot ***split-level*** is a handyman's dream!
>
> The 2700+ square-foot ***split-level house*** is a handyman's dream!

"House" is optional, because ***split-level*** is both a noun and an adjective. Same goes for ***ranch***, ***saltbox***, ***Victorian***, and at least twenty or thirty other styles.

Comment: When colonial is a noun, it means *People who have lived for a long time in a colony* according to Collins dictionary, right? Refer to this link: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/colonial

Comment: Look under definition 3. You'll notice it says "Usually adjective noun." This means "colonial" is usually used as a noun instead of adjective.

Comment: Oh, but they listed these two examples: *[mainly US] 
...the white colonial houses on the north side of the campus.
I sat on the Colonial bench that was just to the left of the office doorway.*. Those are the usage of being adjective.

Comment: I think your answer is right, as I found in merriam-webster dictionary: *b :a product exhibiting colonial style; especially,  often capitalized :a house built in the neoclassical style of the American colonial period* The link: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/colonial

Comment: Yes, if you look up other house styles, they should be listed similarly, as both adjective and noun.

Answer (score 0):

The vast majority of the time, "the"+*adj+singular-noun* refers to a specific or individual item, the same way that "the"+*singular-noun* does.

On occasion, an expression like "the giraffe" may, especially in a textbook, refer to all giraffes, but this isn't the most common use.

There is nothing about putting an adjective in that would cause the phrase to denote multiple items or an entire category.

You seem to be confusing the pattern "the"+*adj*+*noun* with the pattern "the"+*adj* (without a noun), as in "the poor", "the homeless" - which is a different pattern.

In context it would be *possible* for the phrase "the colonial house" to refer to colonial houses in general, following the "giraffe" rule.  Of course, the specification of the size of the house makes such an interpretation much, much less likely, and then the rest of the sentence rules it out completely.